# Screen stuff execution delay

Tags: gnu-screen

I need to press space in two windows at least almost simultaneously to debug my own version of more util. When i'm writing something like

```
: at "#" stuff " "
```

it is working too long (delay about 3 seconds from "command from $USER" to real space pressing)
Is it possible to do it faster?

So if i have 2 windows: my own more and GNU more I wish to press space and immediately see both more's reactions

Comment: I wonder if two separate `at` jobs would execute simultaneously-enough?

Comment: +- second just for usability, but less than 3s

Comment: I tried `screen -X at '#' stuff 'date +%S.%N\n'` on my gnu screen version 4.03.01 and there was only about 2millisecs difference.

Comment: What about time between this command and 'date +%S.%N\n' execution?

Answer (score 0):

`msgwait 0` is an answer to my question

UPD:

Well, i need to visual compare output from default more and my implementation. To make it faster i created session with msgwait 0, attached another terminal started new window with msgwait 0. After wait each time i calls

```
at "#" stuff " "
```

Both of them scrolls by one screen. It's all i need

Sorry for unclear question.

Comment: In what way is that an answer. Please elaborate